# JPA entity relation fetch best practice

Tags: java, jpa, lazy-loading, relationship, dto

We currently try to figure out the best solution to solve a common problem.
Here is the context :

#### Context :

This is how our project is composed

- We have `model` classes, that ensure the data that are passed through are valid.
- We have `domain` classes, these are simple POJO with JPA annotation.

#### Use case

When a request come to the REST API, an object formatted as a `model` object is received (as JSON).
This object is then transformed to a `domain` object to be persisted.
Finally the persisted object is transformed back to a `model` object to be send back to the view.

#### The problem

When we transform `model` object to `domain` object we have to handle the children objects.
But in some case the `model` object doesn't have the children objects loaded, and then we encounter a LazyLoading exception.

#### Concrete example :

The `model` class

```
public class Classroom {

    private final String name;
    private final RoomCapacity roomCapacity;
    private final Set<RoomEquipment> equipments = new HashSet<>();
    private Long id;

    @JsonCreator
    public Classroom(@JsonProperty("name") final String name, @JsonProperty("roomCapacity") final RoomCapacity roomCapacity) {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(name)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot build a " + getClass().getName() + " without a name.");
        }
        if (roomCapacity == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot build a " + getClass().getName() + " without a " + RoomCapacity.class.getName());
        }
        this.name = name;
        this.roomCapacity = roomCapacity;
    }
}
```

The `domain` class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "classroom")
public class ClassroomDomain implements ModelTransformable<Classroom, Long> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "CLASSROOM_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "primaryKey.classroom", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<RoomEquipmentDomain> equipments = new HashSet<>();

    private int capacity;


    public ClassroomDomain(Classroom classroom) {
        if (classroom == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot instantiate a " + getClass().getName() + " with a null " + Classroom.class.getName());
        }
        id = classroom.getId();
        name = classroom.getName();
        capacity = classroom.getRoomCapacity().getMaxCapacity();
        classroom.getEquipments().forEach(e -> equipments.add(new RoomEquipmentDomain(e, this)));
    }

    @Override
    public Classroom toModel() {
        Classroom classroom = new Classroom(name, new RoomCapacity(capacity));
        classroom.setId(id);
        equipments.forEach(e -> classroom.addEquipment(e.toModel()));

        return classroom;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `domain` class have a constructor that takes a `model` object. And the `domain` can be transformed to model.

So when i need to transform the `domain` to `model` it fails because in some case, i do not load the `equipments` lists, then i encounter a LazyLoading exception.

It crashes when i call the `toModel()` in the DAO.

```
public Classroom findOneById(Long id) {
        if (id == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot find a " + Classroom.class.getName() + " with a null id.");
        }
        ClassroomDomain domain = classroomRepository.findOne(id);

        if (domain == null) {
            throw new ClassroomNotFoundException("No " + Classroom.class.getName() + " found for id :" + id);
        }

        return domain.toModel();
    }
```

#### Restriction

- We want to keep the `model` classes, since this application needs to be a common API for multiple programs, so we want a solid model.
- We do not want to put all relationship as `EAGER` loading.

#### Question

How can we transform data from `domain` to `model` without encountering an exception, what are the best practices in this situation.

Comment: Don't return models (which are usually DTOs: Data Transfer Objects) from the DAOs. Return domain classes (which are called entities). Your business logic should work with managed entities, and the transformation of entities to domain and vice-versa belongs, most of the time, to the presentation layer. Make sure all your  logic is run from inside a transaction. Leave the EM opened for the whole duration of the transaction, so that lazy-loading works. Use a Java EE container or Spring to manage the EM and the transactions, in a declarative way, for you.

Comment: Hi, @JBNizet i do use spring, and i don't want to use a transaction, because : the ClassroomDomain.toModel() call Classroom.getEquipments.toModel(), so i don't want to load the whole database each times.

The view is actualy an angular app, so :/ there is no access to the transaction.

Finaly the biggest problem is that the `model` classes have a different structure as the `domain` because of the `@Embedded` entities.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. Why does it call Classroom.getEquipments.toModel() is you don't want to lood the equipments? Why do you think loading equipments would load the whole database? And how does that prevent you from using transactions? If you don't want to load things, then don't load them. If you want to load things, then load them. Not using a transaction is not a way to avoid loading things.

Comment: Here is the point : When and object is requiested (lets say classroom with id 2), we get a `domain` object, but the rest API should returns a `model` object. And in some case the `domain` object will have the equipments loaded, but sometimes it does not.
I don't want a transaction since when i load a object that contains a classroom the `.toModelt()` will load all the classroom, and all the classromm will then load all their equipment, and so on.

Comment: You don't understand what a transaction is. A transaction doesn't automatically load everything as you claim. **Your code** does that. By executing `equipments.forEach(e -> classroom.addEquipment(e.toModel()));`, **you** ask JPA to load the equipments of the class room. And it fails because the persistence context is closed. Using a transaction and leaving the persistence context opened will only make the code do what it is supposed to do: load the equipments successfully. To avoid loading the equipments, the solution is not to avoid transactions. The solution is to avoid executing that code.

Comment: @JBNizet i know what a transaction is, but the point is, i don't want to load the equipment if they are not loaded yet. The `toModel()` operation should be a simple transformation method. I don't whant anymore database call at this level. But yes i agree with you, the solution would be to avoid executing this code, but in some cases, i need to transform equipments list as well.

Comment: Then you need two separate methods. One that loads and populates the equipments, and one that doesn't. Or even two separate DTOs: one with equipments and one without.

Comment: I can't have two DTOs since the dto is a robust model. And i xould like to avoid method duplication. If an object contains 3 list i dont want 9 methods :/. This is why i asked on stackoverflow,  i can figure out a elegent solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finaly decided to go with:

- A method that returns the objects only.
- A method that returns the objects with nested associations. (with JPQL request).

Not the best solution, but i can't find another one.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `Open Session in View (or Transaction in View)` design pattern that you will leave a database connection opened until the end of the user request.

When the application access a lazy collection the Hibernate/JPA will do a database query without a problem, no exception will be threw.

Please refer to : [Source 1](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/four-solutions-to-lazyinitializationexc_05.html), [Source 2](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I use an Angular application as a view. and this is a part of the problem, my backend is just a REST API.

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond again, that is irrelevant. You can perfectly use OSIV with rest controllers. That would be useless in your case though, since you never return entities from your controllers, but DTOs.

Comment: Alright, i didn't knew that what called DTO, i found some instesting leads on google now. Thanks a lot for that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a library for that called [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage). You will still need two methods, but they can reuse the same querying logic if necessary because entity views are applied to existing queries. Note that this will also improve performance as it will only fetch the data you actually map.

I even have an example for your exacty use case, an [external model](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-storage/blob/master/rest/model/src/main/java/com/blazebit/storage/rest/model/AccountRepresentation.java). By extending from the external model and passing data through a [constructor mapping](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-storage/blob/master/rest/impl/src/main/java/com/blazebit/storage/rest/impl/view/AccountRepresentationView.java), you can keep your external model independent and at the same time get good performance and avoid using `EAGER`.